# Groovy build a list from two lists

Tags: groovy

I have two array list in that form:

```
def AllowedExtensions = [ '.mxf', '.mov', '.mp4']
def myPaths = [C:\Temp\Media\Media.c2v, C:\Temp\Media\Media.V2C, C:\Temp\Media\toto\test\巨塔の終わり.mp4, C:\Temp\Media\toto\toto.mxf]
```

I'm trying to build a new list `mySelectedPath` from `myPaths` only if it matches one of the extensions from `AllowedExtensions`
I'm looking for the groovy way to do it but can't get it working correctly.

```
AllowedExtensions.each { mySelectedPath =  myPaths.findAll { it }}
```

Here is my expected result:

```
[C:\Temp\MediaNavigator\toto\toto.mxf, C:\Temp\MediaNavigator\toto\test\巨塔の終わり.mp4]
```

Thank you for any input !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or regex-based:

```
def AllowedExtensions = [ '.mxf', '.mov', '.mp4']
def myPaths = ['C:\\Temp\\Media\\Media.c2v', 'C:\\Temp\\Media\\Media.V2C', 'C:\\Temp\\Media\\toto\\test\\巨塔の終わり.mp4', 'C:\\Temp\\Media\\toto\\toto.mxf']

def regex = /^.*\.(${AllowedExtensions.join( '|' ).replace( '.', '' )})$/

def res = myPaths.grep{ it ==~ regex }

assert res.toString() == '[C:\\Temp\\Media\\toto\\test\\巨塔の終わり.mp4, C:\\Temp\\Media\\toto\\toto.mxf]'
```

Comment: Thank you ! that's the only one which is retrieving all the paths from `myPaths`

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use `findResults`

```
allowedExtensions.findResults { ext -> myPaths.find { it.endsWith ext } }
```

If you want multiple results per extension, try:

```
allowedExtensions.findResults { ext -> myPaths.findAll { it.endsWith ext } }.flatten()
```

Comment: Thank you this was what I'm looking for !
I have updated it to this because my list is built from a recursive folder list with **java.io.file** `allowedExtensions.findResults { ext -> myPaths.find { it.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith ext } }`

Comment: Correction, this one is almost doing it but I'm retrieving only the first path available in the list of `myPaths` not all the paths matching the extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
def AllowedExtensions = [ '.mxf', '.mov', '.mp4']
def myPaths = [
    'C:\\Temp\\Media\\Media.c2v', 
    'C:\\Temp\\Media\\Media.V2C', 
    'C:\\Temp\\Media\\toto\\test\\巨塔の終わり.mp4', 
    'C:\\Temp\\Media\\toto\\toto.mxf'
]

println myPaths.findAll { it.toLowerCase()[it.lastIndexOf('.')..-1] in AllowedExtensions }
```

Comment: I'm not clear why but looks like since `myPaths` is built from java.io.file, this one doesn't work for me.

Comment: if there are paths then add `name` before toLowerCase() :
`myPaths.findAll { it.name.toLowerCase()[it.lastIndexOf('.')..-1] in AllowedExtensions }`